# How to clear swap used area in linux via java

Tags: java, swap, cache-control

I tried the swapoff and swapon in java but I do not see any change with top.

Here is my code:

```
String[] commands= {"/bin/sh","-c","/sbin/swapoff -a && /sbin/swapon -a"};

Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
pr.waitFor();
```

Is something wrong with the strings? 
Wouldn't I see the change after the successful execution of the command in top?

Thanks.

Comment: OT, but why are you trying to do that?

Comment: Does `swapoff -a && swapon -a` work when is run from shell?

Comment: For benchmarking reasons with automated scripts. I cannot stop the script to clear the swap in the shell and then continue...

Comment: What is result of `pr.waitFor()`? Also, are you sure, that user running this does have sufficient privileges (`/sbin` is even not in `PATH` for 'normal' users)?

Comment: If you are having to play with your swap space, you know you have a serious performance problem already as Java doesn't take kindly to being swapped. You don't need a benchmark to tell you that.

Comment: @barti_ddu The result is 255. I run the application with root privileges.@Peter Peter I do not measure the java application. Testing some queries via the java and each query uses swap.

Comment: @Alex: are you sure, `swapon/off` is in your `PATH`? You may want to replace `swapon` -> `/sbin/swapon`, for e.g.

Comment: @barti_ddu I replaced the strings with your suggestion but same behaviour. I recall that I had executed the command in shell and it worked. I had 0 in the swap used area.

Comment: @Alex: have you checked it literally (`/bin/sh -c "/sbin/swapoff -a && /sbin/swapon -a" ; echo $?`)?

Comment: Ok I got the message:swapoff: /dev/sda6: swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory when I run it in the shell. So I suppose I have not enough memory and I cannot do it unless I close the respective application first. Ps: but shouldn't this message be transferred to the output of my java application?

Comment: @Alex: imho, no, since actual `swap[on/off]` calls are not invoked directly (you are invoking shell which executes them in turn). However, you may try to read process' error output stream.

Comment: @Alex: it would be good if you posted your own answer and accept it. Then someone who stumbles upon this page will see that your code is actually correct without reading all these comments and may found it useful (you never know) :)

Answer (score 0):

You should drop cache before swapoff:

```
/bin/echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
/bin/echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
/bin/echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```